# How to not get a new authorization code for OpenID

Tags: openid, openid-connect, openid-provider

Probably the title is not explaining what I mean so let me try to explain with an example.

User logs in to OpenId provider (example.com) with X oauth application (x.example.com). Inside of x.example.com, user wants to move y.example.com which has its own oauth application client_id and its own scopes. So, user needs to get a new token. Once user clicks a link which goes to a page in y.example.com, first thing happen is that to go example.com to get a new authorization code and then with that code, fetch a new token for that application.

Basically what happens is that an openid handshake which checks if user is already authenticated or not. After this all happens, let's say user closed the browser tab for y.example.com but he has a still valid token. Then assume that user in x.example.com clicks to the y.example.com link again but this time, i do not want that user sees again example.com and get a new authorization code as it doesn't make any sense. Also it's not good user experience to show same page again and again and fetch a new token each time.

So, my question is maybe a bit stupid but how could I make logically that user doesn't go each time to the example.com to get a new authorization code? How could I know that user was already logged in and has a valid session for y.example.com?